# why do i need `-t` for `ssh host bash` but `ssh host` runs bash just fine

Tags: ssh

when i do `ssh host` it will log me in to `host` and then run bash. but when i do `ssh host bash` it will just sit there doing seemingly nothing. to get a usable bash prompt i have to provide `-t` like this: `ssh -t host bash`.

actually it does not just sit there doing nothing. when i do `ssh host bash` (without `-t`) it seems that i get a working bash but no prompt. i can do commands like `echo foo` or `ps -ef` and will get usable output. just no prompt.

why do i need `-t` for `ssh host bash` to get a usable bash prompt but `ssh host` runs bash just fine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run:

```
ssh host some    command
```

`ssh` doesn't request a pseudo-tty device to be used on the remote end. The stdout and stderr or the remote commands are pipes instead. `sshd` runs:

```
exec("remote-user-login-shell", ["remote-user-login-shell", "-c", "some command"])
```

That's the `rsh` mode. When you don't specify a command, it enters the `rlogin` mode, where it does start a pseudo-terminal, and runs a login interactive shell session, where it runs:

```
exec("remote-user-login-shell", ["-remote-user-login-shell"])
```

(with a leading `-` in the `argv[0]` to tell the shell it is to behave as a login shell).

You need `-t` when you need to run a specific command interactively (like `bash` or `vi`) in which case `sshd` does create a pseudo-terminal on the remote host to interact with the remote command. [If not, you do **not** want to use `-t`](/a/151963).

In:

```
ssh host bash
```

`bash` doesn't  do nothing, it's just not interactive. It will process the input the same way as it would process a script or like you would get by running `cat | bash`. You can still enter commands and see their output.

Historically, `rsh` (which `ssh` replaced) was actually running `rlogin` when not given any command to run, and `rlogin` was invoking a different service (on a different TCP port) from the `rsh` service.

Comment: Can the answer explain what a "remote tty" is?

Comment: @fraxture, see edit where I've tried to make the wording more consistent.