# Repeated characters SSHing into archlinux machine from mac with iterm2

Tags: arch-linux, zsh, macintosh, iterm2

I'm SSHing into an arch-linux instance. The account in question uses the ZSH shell. When I type characters I get an inconsistent repetition of characters. It looks like this. As you can see, the command actually works, so it's not repeated on the host:

[image]

It looks like a kind of local echo. Does anyone know why this might be happening and how it can be fixed?

Comment: If you don't ssh then no problem?  other shells same problem?

Comment: Outside of ssh, it is normal. Interestingly if I ssh and specify `-t bash` the repeated characters stop. I'm not sure how to interpret that.

Comment: what if you use normal Terminal?

Comment: If I use the normal terminal, the repetition also does not occur

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why do i need \`-t\` for \`ssh host bash\` but \`ssh host\` runs bash just fine](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/402370/why-do-i-need-t-for-ssh-host-bash-but-ssh-host-runs-bash-just-fine).  Lots of duplicates (but reading the manual page is the place to start).

Comment: @ThomasDickey I don't see how the two questions are related. Here it's the plain `ssh host` that isn't working.

Comment: This could be due to `TERM` not being set correctly, either because the local machine uses a value that the remote machine doesn't understand, or because the remote machine is overriding `TERM`. What does `echo $TERM` show when you run it in the local terminal without SSH, on the remote machine with just `ssh host`, and on the remote machine with `ssh host -t bash`?

Comment: OP doesn't state what you inferred.  What's plain is that OP has managed to not actually get a *tty*, and that's why it's already been answered.